# how to access an RDD in another RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have
2 RDD (in pyspark) on the form `rdd1=(id1, value1)` and `rdd2=(id2, value2)` where id are unique(i.e. all id1 are different from id2).

i have third RDD on the form `resultRDD=((id1, id2), value3)`. i want to filter this latter in order to keep only the element with `value3 > (value1+value2)`.

if i access rdd1 and rdd2 i get the following exception:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you
 are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transf
ormation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not
 inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.co
unt() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot
be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SP
ARK-5063.
```

So what it is the best strategy to access rdd1 and rdd2 in order to filter resultRDD?

```
solution1:
```

if i brodcast rdd1 and rdd2 it works but i think it is not the optimized solution since rdd1 and rdd2 are huge.

```
solution2:
```

Instead brodcasting rdd1 and rdd2, we can collect rdd1 and rdd2 and thus we can do the filtering. So please what is the efficient solution in my case?

my function looks like:

```
def filterResultRDD(resultRDD, rdd1, rdd2):


    source = rdd1.collect()
    target = rdd2.collect()
    f = resultRDD.filter(lambda t: t[1] >= getElement(source, t[0][0])+ getElement(target, t[0][1])).cache()
    return f

def getElement(mydata, key):
    return [item[1] for item in mydata if item[0] == key][0]
```

Comment: what about using `join`?

Comment: @OmG how can i use join in this case please?

Comment: transform them to the spark dataframe and using join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First regarding the solutions you have suggested: 
**solution2**: 
Never collect an rdd. 
If you collect an rdd this means that your solution will not be scalable or it means you did not need an rdd in the first place. 
**solution1**: 
Similar to the reference to solution2 but with some exceptions, your case is not one of those exceptions.

As mentioned, the "spark" way to do this is to use "[join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=join#pyspark.RDD.join)".
Of course, there is no need to transform to spark dataframe.

Here is a solution:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([('aa', 1), ('bb', 2), ('cc', 3), ('dd', 4), ('ee', 5)])
rdd3 = sc.parallelize([(('a', 'aa'), 1), (('b', 'dd'), 8), (('e', 'aa'), 34), (('c', 'ab'), 23)])

print rdd3.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1])))\
.join(rdd1)\
.map(lambda x: (x[1][0][0], (x[0], x[1][0][1], x[1][1]))).join(rdd2)\
.filter(lambda x: x[1][0][1] > x[1][0][2] + x[1][1])\
.map(lambda x: ((x[1][0][0], x[0]), x[1][0][1]))\
.collect()

--> [(('b', 'dd'), 8), (('e', 'aa'), 34)]
```

Comment: your solution work well with. for more info. what will be the exception in case if  iwas used brodcasting

Comment: what if the rdds are not of the same length? could you still join them like this?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "length". In the example rdd3 has 4 elements and rdd1 has 5 elements so they are already not the same "length".